# Put One or Two BorderPanes in the Center of another BorderPane

Tags: layout, javafx, borderpane

I have a main window (BorderPane) with some Components in South, North. In Center is a SplitPane. Sometimes I load one other BorderPane with Components in the Center of the SplitPane, sometimes two BorderPanes. All works fine, only that I have to resize the main window manually. Is here any chance to fit one or two Panes in the center and then resize the main window automatically?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the code you already have. That way people can build on that instead of making a bunch of boilerplate/example code themselves. It's preferred that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can use the [edit] button to update your question.

Comment: i put the BorderPane on an AnchorPane!!